How to read string property from DBUS_TYPE_VARIANT?
I have a small Qt app I use dbus to set "org.freedesktop.login1.Session", "SetBrightness" to control the backlight for a laptop display. As part of the program I write the current backlight value to the user's directory so it can be restored on desktop start. Determining the user is simple with getlogin() or getlogin_r(), but since I'm using dbus anyway, why not just grab the ".Name" property and avoid including unistd.h -- seems simple enough -- 8 hours ago.
The Problem - org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Get Returns type 'v' DBUS_TYPE_VARIANT
Examining org.freedesktop.login1, the .Get method is provided and I want to retrieve the .Name property, eg:
$ busctl --no-pager --verbose introspect org.freedesktop.login1 /org/freedesktop/login1/session/1
NAME                                TYPE      SIGNATURE RESULT/VALUE                             FLAGS
org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable interface -         -                                        -
.Introspect                         method    -         s                                        -
org.freedesktop.DBus.Peer           interface -         -                                        -
.GetMachineId                       method    -         s                                        -
.Ping                               method    -         -                                        -
org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties     interface -         -                                        -
.Get                                method    ss        v                                        -
.GetAll                             method    s         a{sv}                                    -
.Set                                method    ssv       -                                        -
.PropertiesChanged                  signal    sa{sv}as  -                                        -
org.freedesktop.login1.Session      interface -         -                                        -
...
.Name                               property  s         "david"                                  const
...

I have no problem retrieving the dbus reply from sending the .Get message on the bus, that I can do with:
#include <dbus/dbus.h>

#define BUFSZ           1024

int dbus_get_property (char *result, int sz, 
                        const char *iface, const char *name)
{
  DBusConnection *dbus_conn = NULL;       /* dbus connection */
  DBusMessage *dbus_msg = NULL;           /* dbus message */
  DBusMessage *dbus_reply = NULL;         /* dbus reply */
  DBusError dbus_error;                   /* dbus error */
  DBusMessageIter iter;
  char *dbus_result = NULL;         /* string from reply */

  /* initialize dbus_error */
  dbus_error_init (&dbus_error);

  /* connect to dbus */
  dbus_conn = dbus_bus_get (DBUS_BUS_SYSTEM, &dbus_error);

  /* create dbus message / validate */
  if ((dbus_msg = dbus_message_new_method_call ("org.freedesktop.login1",
                                  "/org/freedesktop/login1/session/auto",
                                  "org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties",
                                  "Get")) == NULL) {
    perror (dbus_error.name);
    perror (dbus_error.message);
    puts ("error: dbus msg");
    return -1;
  }

  /* append arguments to dbus message / validate */
  if (dbus_message_append_args (dbus_msg, DBUS_TYPE_STRING, &iface,
                                          DBUS_TYPE_STRING, &name,
                                          DBUS_TYPE_INVALID) == false) {
    puts ("error: dbus append");
    return -1;
  }

  /* invoke dbus rpc, block for reply */
  if ((dbus_reply = dbus_connection_send_with_reply_and_block (dbus_conn,
                                              dbus_msg,
                                              DBUS_TIMEOUT_USE_DEFAULT,
                                              &dbus_error)) == NULL) {
    perror (dbus_error.name);
    perror (dbus_error.message);
    puts ("error: dbus conn send");
    return -1;
  }
  ...

This is where the problem I can't seems to solve comes in. dbus_reply message has the result argument as type 'v' (DBUS_TYPE_VARIANT) with the first element being the string property I want. Attempting to get the argument with dbus_message_get_args_valist() results in the error:
dbus[148675]: you can only read arrays and basic types with _dbus_message_iter_get_args_valist for now

Okay -- Let's Go With That
So I try initializing an iterator and using dbus_message_get_args_valist(), e.g
  if (dbus_message_iter_init (dbus_reply, &iter) == false) {
    perror (dbus_error.name);
    perror (dbus_error.message);
    
    puts ("error: dbus iter init");
    return -1;
  }
  
  int current_type;
  if ((current_type = dbus_message_iter_get_arg_type (&iter)) != DBUS_TYPE_VARIANT) {
    printf ("error current type: %d (DBUS_TYPE_STRING: %d, DBUS_TYPE_VARIANT: %d)\n", 
            current_type, DBUS_TYPE_STRING, DBUS_TYPE_VARIANT);
    return -1;
  }
  
  dbus_message_iter_get_basic (&iter, &dbus_result);
  ...

Which fails because the type returned is DBUS_TYPE_VARIANT, e.g.
dbus[149385]: type variant 118 not a basic type
  D-Bus not built with -rdynamic so unable to print a backtrace
Aborted (core dumped)

The doxydoc DBusMessage Documentation has had me chasing solutions in circles. My chat with the Rubber-duck tells me I am missing the way of converting the DBUS_TYPE_VARIANT to va_list so I can extract the property with va_arg -- but attempting to find the proper way of doing that has eluded me. I'm stuck...
My current NON-working (but completely reproducible example) is:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#include <dbus/dbus.h>

#define BUFSZ           1024

int dbus_get_property (char *result, int sz, 
                        const char *iface, const char *name)
{
  DBusConnection *dbus_conn = NULL;       /* dbus connection */
  DBusMessage *dbus_msg = NULL;           /* dbus message */
  DBusMessage *dbus_reply = NULL;         /* dbus reply */
  DBusError dbus_error;                   /* dbus error */
  DBusMessageIter iter;
  char *dbus_result = NULL;               /* string from reply */
  // DBusVariant *dbus_result = NULL;        /* to derive string from reply */
  // va_list dbus_result;                    /* to derive string from reply */

  /* initialize dbus_error */
  dbus_error_init (&dbus_error);

  /* connect to dbus */
  dbus_conn = dbus_bus_get (DBUS_BUS_SYSTEM, &dbus_error);

  /* create dbus message / validate */
  if ((dbus_msg = dbus_message_new_method_call ("org.freedesktop.login1",
                                  "/org/freedesktop/login1/session/auto",
                                  "org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties",
                                  "Get")) == NULL) {
    perror (dbus_error.name);
    perror (dbus_error.message);
    puts ("error: dbus msg");
    return -1;
  }

  /* append arguments to dbus message / validate */
  if (dbus_message_append_args (dbus_msg, DBUS_TYPE_STRING, &iface,
                                          DBUS_TYPE_STRING, &name,
                                          DBUS_TYPE_INVALID) == false) {
    puts ("error: dbus append");
    return -1;
  }

  /* invoke dbus rpc, block for reply */
  if ((dbus_reply = dbus_connection_send_with_reply_and_block (dbus_conn,
                                              dbus_msg,
                                              DBUS_TIMEOUT_USE_DEFAULT,
                                              &dbus_error)) == NULL) {
    perror (dbus_error.name);
    perror (dbus_error.message);
    puts ("error: dbus conn send");
    return -1;
  }
  
  /* get result string */

  if (dbus_message_iter_init (dbus_reply, &iter) == false) {
    perror (dbus_error.name);
    perror (dbus_error.message);
    
    puts ("error: dbus iter init");
    return -1;
  }
  
  int current_type;
  if ((current_type = dbus_message_iter_get_arg_type (&iter)) != DBUS_TYPE_VARIANT) {
    printf ("error current type: %d (DBUS_TYPE_STRING: %d, DBUS_TYPE_VARIANT: %d)\n", 
            current_type, DBUS_TYPE_STRING, DBUS_TYPE_VARIANT);
    return -1;
  }
  
  // dbus_message_iter_next (&iter);
  /*
   *  ./dbus-get-property
   *  dbus[148881]: type variant 118 not a basic type
   *    D-Bus not built with -rdynamic so unable to print a backtrace
   *  Aborted (core dumped)
   *
   */
  dbus_message_iter_get_basic (&iter, &dbus_result);
  
  /*
  ./dbus-get-property
  dbus[148675]: you can only read arrays and basic types with _dbus_message_iter_get_args_valist for now

  if (dbus_message_get_args_valist (dbus_reply, &dbus_error, DBUS_TYPE_VARIANT,
                           dbus_result) == false) {
    perror (dbus_error.name);
    perror (dbus_error.message);
    puts ("error: dbus get args");
    return -1;
  }
  
  char *p = va_arg (dbus_result, char*);
  
  if (p == NULL) {
    puts ("error: dbus_result NULL");
    return -1;
  }
  
  if (strcmp (p, "david") != 0) {
    return -1;
  }
  */
  
  if (dbus_result == NULL) {
    puts ("error: dbus_result NULL");
    return -1;
  }
  
  if (strcmp (dbus_result, "david") != 0) {
    return -1;
  }
  
  if (strlen (dbus_result) + 1 < (size_t)sz) {
    strcpy (result, dbus_result);
  }

  /* unref reply, message and connection */
  dbus_message_unref (dbus_reply);
  dbus_message_unref (dbus_msg);
  dbus_connection_unref (dbus_conn);
  
  return 0;
}


int main (void) {

  char name[BUFSZ] = "";
  
  if (dbus_get_property (name, BUFSZ, "org.freedesktop.login1.Session", "Name") < 0) {
    return 1;
  }
  
  // printf ("Name: '%s'\n", name);
  puts ("no error!");
}

What is the proper way to handle the DBUS_TYPE_VARIANT argument attached to dbus_reply in order to extract the string for the .Name property?

I'm slightly curious – given that it's a Qt app, why use libdbus directly instead of Qt's own QDBus?

This is a "feature" of my relative lack of expertise in Qt or DBus and the fact that it is written to work with both Qt3 and Qt5. Short answer, the first and what seemed the most straight-forward path at the time was to simply include dbus.h and write the backlight change through the "Brightness" method to use as a slot for the ValueChanged signal from a slider and spinbox. Along the way I learned about the QDBus and GDBus alternatives. I'll probably go back and use the QDBus interface, but the time spent was worth the learning, even if I lost a bit of hair during the ordeal.

In that case, since you also depend on systemd, its sd-bus library might be a somewhat more modern option.

DBUS_TYPE_VARIANT is a dbus container and, you must recurse the original iterator initialized from the dbus reply using a sub-iterator to obtain the values.
The documentation is there, as far as what the API is, but it is a bit lacking on how to put the pieces together. While working on the question I was curious about recursion of the iterator, but had nothing that was telling me that is what was needed. (it's likely buried somewhere1). So I had initialized the sub iterator and then checked its signature with dbus_message_iter_get_signature(). That came back as 's' and the light-bulb of understanding winked on.
The following retrieves the username Name property for the current login session using the Get method for org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.
Note: in the comment checking dbus_message_iter_get_arg_type() for the sub-iterator, this is only checking for a string property. You would need to add checks for additional types depending on what property you were retrieving.
The WORKING code:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#include <dbus/dbus.h>

#define BUFSZ           1024

int dbus_get_property (char *result, int sz, 
                        const char *iface, const char *name)
{
  DBusConnection *dbus_conn = NULL;       /* dbus connection */
  DBusMessage *dbus_msg = NULL;           /* dbus message */
  DBusMessage *dbus_reply = NULL;         /* dbus reply */
  DBusError dbus_error;                   /* dbus error */
  DBusMessageIter iter,                   /* iterator for dbus_reply */
                  sub;                    /* sub-iterator to recurse iter */
  char *dbus_result = NULL;               /* string from reply */
  int current_type;                       /* int to validate sub-iter type */

  /* initialize dbus_error */
  dbus_error_init (&dbus_error);

  /* connect to dbus */
  dbus_conn = dbus_bus_get (DBUS_BUS_SYSTEM, &dbus_error);

  /* create dbus message / validate */
  if ((dbus_msg = dbus_message_new_method_call ("org.freedesktop.login1",
                                  "/org/freedesktop/login1/session/auto",
                                  "org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties",
                                  "Get")) == NULL) {
    perror (dbus_error.name);
    perror (dbus_error.message);
    
    return -1;
  }

  /* append arguments to dbus message / validate */
  if (dbus_message_append_args (dbus_msg, DBUS_TYPE_STRING, &iface,
                                          DBUS_TYPE_STRING, &name,
                                          DBUS_TYPE_INVALID) == false) {
    return -1;
  }

  /* invoke dbus rpc, block for reply */
  if ((dbus_reply = dbus_connection_send_with_reply_and_block (dbus_conn,
                                              dbus_msg,
                                              DBUS_TIMEOUT_USE_DEFAULT,
                                              &dbus_error)) == NULL) {
    perror (dbus_error.name);
    perror (dbus_error.message);
    
    return -1;
  }
  
  /* get result property */
  
  /* initialize iterator for DBUS_TYPE_VARIANT container */
  if (dbus_message_iter_init (dbus_reply, &iter) == false) {
    perror (dbus_error.name);
    perror (dbus_error.message);
    
    return -1;
  }
  
  /* initialize sub-iterator to recurse into variant container */
  dbus_message_iter_recurse (&iter, &sub);
  
  /* validate DBUS_TYPE_STRING signature for sub-iterator
   * (specific for this example, you would need to handle additional types)
   */
  if ((current_type = dbus_message_iter_get_arg_type (&sub)) !=
        DBUS_TYPE_STRING) {
    fprintf (stderr, "error current type: %d (DBUS_TYPE_STRING: %d)\n", 
            current_type, DBUS_TYPE_STRING);
    
    return -1;
  }
  
  /* get basic type (string) from sub-iterator */
  dbus_message_iter_get_basic (&sub, &dbus_result);
  
  /* validate result not NULL */
  if (dbus_result == NULL) {
    fputs ("error: dbus_result NULL.\n", stderr);
    
    return -1;
  }
  
  if (strlen (dbus_result) + 1 < (size_t)sz) {
    strcpy (result, dbus_result);
  }

  /* unref reply, message and connection */
  dbus_message_unref (dbus_reply);
  dbus_message_unref (dbus_msg);
  dbus_connection_unref (dbus_conn);
  
  return 0;
}


int main (void) {

  char name[BUFSZ] = "";
  
  /* send dbus message to get property from interface */
  if (dbus_get_property (name, BUFSZ, 
                         "org.freedesktop.login1.Session", "Name") < 0) {
    return 1;
  }
  
  printf ("Name: '%s'\n", name);
}

Example Use/Output
$ ./dbus-get-property
Name: 'david'

Hopefully this will save others the same bit of frustration digesting dbus property retrieval.
Minimal gcc compile string for the curious:
gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c11 -O3 -o dbus-get-property dbus-get-property.c $(pkg-config --cflags --libs dbus-1)


Footnotes:

There is general reference for initializing a sub-iterator for a container in the comments for dbus_signature_iter_get_current_type()

